# How to Support Localization by mapping two entities to one POCO in EF 4

Tags: .net, entity-framework, localization, entity-framework-4, poco

I've this simple Entities from DB tables
[image]

**But i want my POCO classes to be just two classes:**

```
public class Country
{
    public string ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LocalName { get; set; } // this localized

    public string Region { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string CountryID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } //this localized

    public double? Longitude { get; set; }

    public double? Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

Then i want Localized properties "`LocalName` for the `Country` and `Name` for the `City`" to be filled by my context.

So how to map this Entities to POCO Classes?

And is there better way to do that?

**Or i should make manual converting from Entities to my Model and add one more tier ?**

Please help me to take decision .

.

***: Additional information:***

I made my `ObjectContext` to deal with my POCO but when i try to fill my Additional property "`LocalName`" in repository i get this error:

> ```
> The entity or complex type 'Site.Country'  cannot be constructed
> ```
>
> in a LINQ to Entities query.

and this is the method in my Repository:

```
       public IQueryable<Country> GetCountries()
       {
           return from country in context.Countries
                  join countryCul in context.CountriesCultures 
                  on country.Code equals countryCul.CountryID
                  where countryCul.LangID == "en"
                  select new Country
                             {
                                 Code = country.Code,
                                 LocalName = countryCul.LocalName,
                                 Name = country.Name,
                                 Region = country.Region,
                             };
       }
```

**I don't know how to fill "`LocalName`" property within linq statement**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a solution with ViewModel class, you can pick up these:

For wrapping City with it's selected LocalLanguage

```
public class CityLocolized
{
    public City City { get; set; }
    public String LocalName { get; set; }
}
```

Here, we chose the either default so with if else no join, else chose from CityCulture table

```
string lang = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
List<CityLocolized> citiesLocalized = null;
if (lang == "en") // which is default in db
{
    citiesLocalized = (from c in fke.Cities
                    select new CityLocolized
                    {
                        City = c,
                        LocalName = c.Name
                    }
                    ).ToList();
}
else // for other languages 
{
    citiesLocalized = (from c in fke.Cities
                    join cc in fke.CityCultures
                    on c.Id equals cc.CityId
                    where cc.LangId == lang
                    select new CityLocolized
                    {
                        City = c,
                        LocalName = cc.LocalName
                    }).ToList();

}
```

and this one for passing View:

```
   ViewData["CitiesLocolized"] = new SelectList(citiesLocalized, "City.Id", "LocalName");
```

finally at view:

```
  <%:Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityId,  ViewData["CitiesLocolized"] as SelectList)%>
```

i think this is it.

moguzalp

Comment: But EF can't deal with your `CityLocalized` class. But i want EF to deal directly with my model so i can make queries and return ViewModels with just the data wanted not to fetch unnecessary data from DB.

Comment: ViewModel is the best for this issue. Thanks :)